# email address validation + java regularExpression

Tags: java

I have a email address field and validating using `type='email'` in front end. But the requirement is if user is entering `"none"`, this also should be valid in email input field. If user enter `"email address"` or `"none"` both should be valid. Please let me know the regular expression code in java to validate both. Thank you.

Comment: Provide examples that your regex needs to identify and those it needs to reject.

Comment: have you tried searching in google.. many links from SO itself buddy

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama : Thanks buddy

Comment: if user enter " none" in the email input field, it should be accept and no other character to be accepted apart from valid email and "none" text.

Comment: You could use : `none | <your_regular_regex_from_google_foo>`

Answer (score 1):

Based on what your provided, this should work:

```
^none(?!\S)|[\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

This matches every string, which is either `none` or in the format

```
[letters, underscore, %, ., +, -]@[letters, ., -].[TLD]
example                          @gmail          .com
```

Comment: when i tried to use the above regEx, throwing compile time error : Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Comment: @RaviKChowdary If you're using java, you need to escape every \. Use this: `^none(?!\\S)|[\\w.%+-]+@[\\w.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$`

Comment: The above regEx is not validating when i entered "None" in email text input field. It is still throwing "not valid email".

Comment: If you want to make every possible way of writing "none" correct (e.g. None, NoNe, NONE, NONe, etc.), then use the case-insensitive option

Comment: when i enter "none" also is not validating and email also not validating properly.

Comment: @RaviKChowdary Then there's a problem in how you validate it, because it works for me